# Join table query returns multiple results from right table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm new to access and Have pulled tog ether a query in the GUI.

I have a Join set up so all customers who have complained are in the left table and all work completed is in the right table.

Both table have the customers reference number so I've joined based on that.

Customers may complain before we've carried out any work so the table is a left Join.

The problem I have is a customer may have had multiple work items, so when I create the join each row in the complaints table is being returned multiple times if they have had more than on work item carried out.

I need to add some logic to the joins so it only brings back a single work item for each complaint. Where multiple work items are present are want the query to return the work item with the date closets to the date of the complaint but never after it.

If the complaint has no work items that occur before it I still want the complain to be shown but with data from the work item.

I only really know how to use the designer GUI but the SQL looks like this at the moment:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT [CEAR326 Master Data fo access1].ID, 
    ReportingCategory.ReportingCategory, 
    [CEAR326 Master Data fo access1].Category, 
    [CEAR326 Master Data fo access1].[Sub Category], 
    [CEAR326 Master Data fo access1].[Contact Partner], 
    main_Tbl_ServiceOrder.ServiceProduct, SOType.SOType, 
    Format([Actual Date From],"mmm-yy") AS [Date], 
    [CEAR326 Master Data fo access1].[Actual Date From],
    main_Tbl_ServiceOrder.BasicStartDate, 
    [CEAR326 Master Data fo access1].Smart_Flag

    FROM (([CEAR326 Master Data fo access1] 
    LEFT JOIN main_Tbl_ServiceOrder ON [CEAR326 Master Data fo access1].[Contact Partner] = main_Tbl_ServiceOrder.BusinessPartnerNumber) 
    LEFT JOIN ReportingCategory ON [CEAR326 Master Data fo access1].Category = ReportingCategory.Category) LEFT JOIN SOType ON main_Tbl_ServiceOrder.ServiceProduct = SOType.ServiceOrder

    WHERE (((main_Tbl_ServiceOrder.BasicStartDate)<="actual Date from" Or (main_Tbl_ServiceOrder.BasicStartDate)="0" Or (main_Tbl_ServiceOrder.BasicStartDate) Is Null))


    ORDER BY [CEAR326 Master Data fo access1].[Contact Partner], main_Tbl_ServiceOrder.BasicStartDate;
```

I believe the Select distinct isn't working as required due to the  line

```
main_Tbl_ServiceOrder.ServiceProduct, SOType.SOType,
```

This is where I want my where statement to come in and select the relevant service order by looking at the date of the service order in relation to the date of the CEAR [Actual Date From].

I also think there would be an issue with the current WHERE statement returning multiple Service orders if they occur before the CEAR. I'd only want to return the one closest to the CEAR date.

Comment: Any chance you can come up with a simpler example (say two tables with only a few columns each) that exhibits the same problem, preferably with sample data and expected results?

Comment: Your `WHERE` condition doesn't look right. I assume `BasicStartDate` is a date field, so you need the `"Actual Date From"` criteria to be `(main_Tbl_ServiceOrder.BasicStartDate)<=[CEAR326 Master Data fo access1].[Actual Date From]`. Otherwise you're comparing dates to the text string "actual Date from", which looks incorrect to me. You still may have duplicates though, so I'd create a stacked query after this to take the `MAX([BasicStartDate])` from this query's results. That should leave only the service order closest to the CEAR date without being after the CEAR date.

Answer (score 0):

This uses

1. Complaints table with ComplaintID as the key and fields for Customer and Complaint_Date
2. WorkOrders table with WorkOrderID as they key and fields for Customer and WorkOrder_date

I assumed there is only one work order per customer per date.  If this isn't true, you may need to use an autonumber field for the WorkOrders instead of the date field in the selection criteria

You should be able to customize this with your table names and field names.

```
SELECT Complaints.ComplaintID, Complaints.Customer, Complaints.Complaint_date, WorkOrders.WorkOrderID, WorkOrders.WorkOrder_date
FROM Complaints LEFT JOIN WorkOrders ON Complaints.Customer = WorkOrders.Customer
WHERE (((WorkOrders.WorkOrder_date) Is Null Or (WorkOrders.WorkOrder_date)=(select max(WorkOrder_Date) from WorkOrders T where T.customer=Complaints.customer and T.WorkOrder_date<Complaint_date)));
```